# Finding Streamlines: How to solve this ODE? Is there a easier way?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I was given the velocity vector field $\mathbf{\vec{v}}(x, y, z)$ and was asked to find the streamlines $\mathbf{\vec{r}}(t)$ in my exam:

$$\mathbf{\vec{v}}(x, y, z) = -\dfrac yx \hat i + 4x \hat j + 0 \hat k$$

This is what I did:

$$z(t) = \int 0 dt = C_1$$

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = -\dfrac {y(t)}{x(t)};\; \dfrac{dy}{dt} = 4x(t)$$

But these two equations are coupled. So, I tried to decouple them like this:

$$y = -x\dfrac{dx}{dt}$$

$$\implies \dfrac{dy}{dt} = -\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 - x\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}$$

$$\implies x\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} + \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + 4x = 0$$

Now, what do I do? Is there a easier way?

Comment: Small note, we call such equations *coupled* and we look to decouple them, not entangled/disentangled.

Comment: @Tony S.F. Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $2$ dimensions you can transform a system
$$\dot x=-{y\over x},\quad \dot y=4x$$
directly into a $(x,y)$-ODE for the stream lines: Write
$$y'={\dot y\over\dot x}=-{4x^2\over y}$$
and obtain
$$(y^2)'=-8x^2\ .$$
It follows that the stream lines are given by
$$y^2+{8\over3}x^3=C\ .$$
Of course the information about the time dependence is lost in this process.

Comment: Thanx. I guess I should have done that. But I thought I couldn't find the functions that way. But it does specify the streamlines

Answer (score 1):

setting $$u(x)=\frac{dx(t)}{dt}$$
so we get $$4x+u(x)^2+x\frac{du(x)}{dx}u(x)=0$$ or
$$x\frac{du(x)}{dx}u(x)+u(x)^2=-4x$$
and we substitute $$u(x)=v(x)^2$$ with $$\frac{du(x)}{dx}=2v(x)\frac{dv(x)}{dx}$$
and we get
$$\frac{dv(x)}{dx}+2\frac{v(x)}{x}=-8$$ with the integrating factorn $$\mu(x)=x^2$$
$$x^2\frac{dv(x)}{dx}+2xv(x)=-8x^2$$
and we have $$\int \frac{d}{dx}(x^2v(x))dx=\int -8x^2dx$$
and we get $$x^2v(x)=-\frac{8}{3}x^3+C_1$$
i think now it is right!

Comment: i have corrected my post, sorry for that

Comment: Are there any missing steps? Am sorry I have to ask again coz I am not able to follow all the steps. Thnx in advance :)

Comment: which step is not clear?

Comment: First, how $u \dfrac{du}{dx} = \dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}$

Comment: it is $$\frac {d^2x(t)}{dt^2}=\frac {d}{dx}\left(\frac {x(t)}{dt}\right)=\frac{du(x)}{dt}=\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{du(x)}{dx}=u(x)\frac{du(x)}{dx}$$

Comment: and now your next question

Comment: How does $\dfrac{du(x)}{dx} = 2 v(x) \dfrac{dv(x)}{dx}$ follow from $x \dfrac{du(x)}{dx} u(x) + u(x)^2 = −4x$, $u(x) = v(x)^2$ and $\dfrac{du(x)}{dx} = 2 v(x) \dfrac{dv(x)}{dx}$?

Comment: this is the chain rule $$u'(x)=2v(x)v'(x)$$

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask how $\dfrac{dv(x)}{dx} + 2 \dfrac{v(x)}{x} = −8$ follows from those things.

Comment: Can you explain how $\dfrac{dv(x)}{dx} + 2 \dfrac{v(x)}{x} = −8$ follows from $x\dfrac{du(x)}{dx}u(x) + u(x)^2 = −4x$, $u(x) = v(x)^2$ and $\dfrac{du(x)}{dx} = 2v(x)\dfrac{dv(x)}{dx}$

Comment: This is what I am getting: $$2x v(x)^3 \dfrac{dv(x)}{dx} + v(x)^4 = -4x$$ implies $$\dfrac{dv(x)}{dx} + \dfrac{v(x)}{2x} = \dfrac{-2}{v(x)^3}$$ not $$\dfrac{dv(x)}{dx} + 2 \dfrac{v(x)}{x} = −8$$